# Custom searchsortedfirst method

Tags: arrays, sorting, vector, julia

I'm kinda new in Julia lang, so I'm still struggling with reading Julia documentation. Here is a piece of it and I am looking for explanation specifically the **bolded** part.

> Base.Sort.searchsortedfirst — Function.
>
> ***searchsortedfirst(a, x, [by=,] [lt=,]
>   [rev=false])***
>
> Returns the index of the first value in a greater than or equal to x,
>   according to the specified order. Returns length(a)+1 if x is greater
>   than all values in a. a is assumed to be sorted.

[Website](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/sort/)

My array looks like this:

```
A = Vector{Record}()
```

where

```
type Record
     y::Int64
     value::Float64
end
```

Now here is my problem. I would like to call above-mentioned method on my array and obtain Record where given x equals y in this Record (Record.y == x). Guess I have to write 'by' transfrom or 'lt' comparator? or both?

Any help would be appraciated :)

Comment: Sounds like `find(r->r.y == x, A)` to me?

Comment: @crstnbr Got sorted array so it would be cool if function was less than O(n). Thanks for that proposition tho :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@crstnbr has provided a perfectly good answer for the case of one-off uses of `searchsortedfirst`. I thought it worth adding that there is also a more permanent solution. If your type `Record` exhibits a natural ordering, then just extend `Base.isless` and `Base.isequal` to your new type. The following example code shows how this works for some new type you might define:

```
struct MyType ; x::Float64 ; end  #Define some type of my own
yvec = MyType.(sort!(randn(10)))  #Build a random vector of my type
yval = MyType(0.0)                #Build a value of my type
searchsortedfirst(yvec, yval)     #ERROR: this use of searchsortedfirst will throw a MethodError since julia doesn't know how to order MyType
Base.isless(y1::MyType, y2::MyType)::Bool = y1.x < y2.x   #Extend (aka overload) isless so it is defined for the new type
Base.isequal(y1::MyType, y2::MyType)::Bool = y1.x == y2.x #Ditto for isequal
searchsortedfirst(yvec, yval)     #Now this line works
```

Some points worth noting:

**1)** In the step where I overload `isless` and `isequal`, I preface the method definition with `Base.`. This is because the `isless` and `isequal` functions are originally defined in `Base`, where `Base` refers to the core julia package that is automatically loaded every time you start julia. By prefacing with `Base.`, I ensure that my new methods are added to the current set of methods for these two functions, rather than replacing them. Note, I could also achieve this by omitting `Base.` but including a line beforehand of `import Base: isless, isequal`. Personally, I prefer the way I've done it above (for the overly pedantic, you can also do both).

**2)** I can define `isless` and `isequal` however I want. It is my type and my method extensions. So you can choose whatever you think is the natural ordering for your new type.

**3)** The operators `<`. `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>`, all actually just call `isless` and `isequal` under the hood, so all of these operators will now work with your new type, eg `MyType(1.0) > MyType(2.0)` returns `false`.

**4)** Any julia function that uses the comparative operators above will now work with your new type, as long as the function is defined parametrically (which almost everything in `Base` is).

Comment: Oh, that helps a lot! So basically what you are doing is you overload a method in this 'Base' class, I guess? Could you tell more about it's usage? or link some website? Thanks for your effort in clarification!

Comment: @J.Kennsy I've significantly re-worked my answer to include some new info and hopefully answer your question. Let me know if there is anything else that needs clarification.

Answer (score 3):

You can just define a custom less-than operation and give it to `searchsortedfirst` via `lt` keyword argument:

```
julia> type Record
            y::Int64
            value::Float64
       end

julia> A = Vector{Record}()
0-element Array{Record,1}

julia> push!(A, Record(3,3.0))
1-element Array{Record,1}:
 Record(3, 3.0)

julia> push!(A, Record(4,3.0))
2-element Array{Record,1}:
 Record(3, 3.0)
 Record(4, 3.0)

julia> push!(A, Record(5,3.0))
3-element Array{Record,1}:
 Record(3, 3.0)
 Record(4, 3.0)
 Record(5, 3.0)

julia> searchsortedfirst(A, 4, lt=(r,x)->r.y<x)
2
```

Here, `(r,x)->r.y<x` is an [anonymous function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions-1) defining your custom less-than. It takes two arguments (the elements to be compared). The first will be the elements from `A`, the second is the fixed element to compare to.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for explanation :)

Comment: Nice answer. I was going to add in a comment here that you could also extend `Base.isless` and `Base.isequal` but it ended up being a bit long so I wrote it as a second answer. But I think both approaches are quite "julian".